# MySQL ROW_COUNT() not working

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
DELETE FROM c_email WHERE code = '67890' AND user_id = '2';
SELECT ROW_COUNT() AS row_1;
```

I want to get a field named `row_1`, with number of rows deleted, but it seems not to work...

Comment: @juergend It outputs nothing...

Comment: How do you run these queries?

Comment: How may rows were affected due to `delete` and what did `select row_count()` fetched?

Comment: This is what I get through PHPMyAdmin `SELECT ROW_COUNT( ) AS row_1;# Rows: 1
DELETE FROM c_email WHERE code = '67890' AND user_id = '2';# Affected rows: 1`

Comment: Do you want to run this query in a php page or what else?

Comment: @kiks73 I run this query in PHP code and as SELECT I want to get a column named row_1 with the number of affected rows by DELETE

Comment: This link must help you i guess http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **not** depricated `$mysqli->affected_rows;` as shown in [this document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

> **Returnvalue**: An integer greater than zero indicates the number of rows affected or retrieved. Zero indicates that no records were updated for an UPDATE statement, no rows matched the WHERE clause in the query or that no query has yet been executed. -1 indicates that the query returned an error.

And a small example from that same [website](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Insert rows */
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE Language SELECT * from CountryLanguage");
printf("Affected rows (INSERT): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

$mysqli->query("ALTER TABLE Language ADD Status int default 0");

/* update rows */
$mysqli->query("UPDATE Language SET Status=1 WHERE Percentage > 50");
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

/* delete rows */
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM Language WHERE Percentage < 50");
printf("Affected rows (DELETE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

/* select all rows */
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT CountryCode FROM Language");
printf("Affected rows (SELECT): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

$result->close();

/* Delete table Language */
$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE Language");

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is using PDO.

assuming you can do some research, set up a PDO connection and be sure to specify this option:

```
$db = new PDO ($dsn,$user,$pass,array (
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>TRUE,
));
```

then, prepare and execute your statement. **I don't know of any mysql command which actually selects deleted rows**. you'll have to go for `rowCount()`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM c_email WHERE code = '67890' AND user_id = '2'");
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

**But you want to select a second query in the same call** so we'll do it with normal selecting of existing rows

```
$stmt = $db->prepare(
 'UPDATE c_email SET code=1376 WHERE user_id=3;
  SELECT user_id FROM c_email WHERE code=1376;'
);
$stmt->execute(); // this executes both statements, and sets some internal pointer towards the first.
$stmt->nextRowset(); // it's the next one that interests us
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // let's get the value
echo $row['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @before:=(SELECT count(*) FROM c_email);

DELETE FROM c_email  WHERE code = '67890' AND user_id = '2';

SELECT @after:=(SELECT count(*) FROM c_email);
COMMIT;
SELECT @before-@after AS DELETED;